# Two kits of three DDR3 memory sticks mixed. Are they same?

Tags: memory, compatibility, dual-channel, triple-channel

I have bought two memory kits, each having three DDR3 modules for triple-channel setup. Looking at the memory modules serial stickers, I couldn’t find a clue about how to identify, that the modules in the 1 kit have some serial marker that they go in kit

I ask because it could happen that they get mixed (or there were already multiple dual-channel modules installed). Is there a way to identify which modules are from the original kit, in order to be able to match them correctly again? Would posting their serial numbers help?

Because I bought two kits at once could all six actually be the same? That is, compatible even if they are mixed?

The serial/product numbers on the modules were either all the same, or completely different, so no hint to identify if the modules belong to only one box.

Answer (score 4):

You can download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and read out all your information, including the serial numbers of your RAMs. However, it *probably* shouldn't matter if you mix those.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can [identify RAM](http://www.semiconductorstore.com/pdf/newsite/Kingston/MKF_1183.3_Identifying_VRmemory.pdf) by checking for a K-number near the end of the serial.

Comment: KVR1333D3D4R9SK3/24GI  is the kit ordering merchant SKU,  the K3 just means its kit of 3 modules,  but this same SKU will be kept as long the module is sold,  the question is, having 2 such kits with same batch, all 6 modules are compatible and can be mixed? or is there something that differs those 2 kits, and if it matters, if there is some flag, label that can be a guide to identoify original pieces together